How to forward ports with IPv6 using iptables
I have two separated networks and there is one computer that is in both of them.
I want to forward connections made to that computer on one port from one of the networks to a port on a specific computer in the other network.
I am able to do this in ipv4 by doing
sysctl -w  net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

and adding the following rule to iptables
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING  -p tcp --dport 49000 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.2.1:49000

I have tried doing the same in ipv6 with
sysctl -w  net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1

and
ip6tables -t nat -A PREROUTING  -p tcp --dport 49000 -j DNAT --to-destination [fc00::3]:49000

but it is not working.
Does anyone know why this doesn't work and what should I be doing instead?
UPDATE: The steps I explained here actually work. The problem was the way I was testing the ipv6 connectivity, my test was using a connection that only had an ipv4 address so it wasn't working. After assigning it an ipv6 address I realized the port forwarding was actually working.


Look at the ip6tables rule counters (leftmost columns in the -L -v list); is the rule being hit at all? 2) Investigate using tcpdump or Wireshark, whether it really doesn't work at all or whether it does something else?


Thank you for answering, in the end it was my fault, my test for checking ipv6 connectivity was wrong and in the end ipv6 forwarding was always working.
